# rundeck SSH Authentication failure

Tags: ssh, rundeck

I run Rundeck v4.1.2, using docker-compose.

I have created a test key pair. I have entered the private key into key storage under the path `keys/test` using the GUI, and configured the target node to require it for SSH access. I have added the public key under `/home/rundeck/.ssh/authorized_keys`  on the target node.

The resources.xml file looks like this:

```
server18:
  nodename: server18
  hostname: server18.rc-group.local
  osVersion: 18.04
  osFamily: unix
  osArch: amd64
  description: target-test
  osName: Ubuntu
  username: rundeck
  ssh-authentication: privateKey
  ssh-privateKey-storage-path: keys/test
```

When I try to connect using command line SSH and the same private key, it works fine. So the key is fine, and the target node config is fine.

When, in the GUI, I try to run the "hostname" command on the same target node, I get:

```
Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "server18". Make sure your resource definitions and credentials are up to date.
```

Can someone spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi! Could you follow this? https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6022#issuecomment-624678947

Comment: Yes I have seen this article. To the extent that it applies to me, I have not missed anything. Are you referring to something in particular?

Comment: does the model source it's defined as XML? (because the definition is in YAML format).

Comment: Yes, it's in YAML, there is no problem with that. Rundeck recognizes it and parses it.

Comment: Use `ssh-key-storage-path` attribute instead of `ssh-privateKey-storage-path` in your node definition.

Comment: Great! Let me add it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh-key-storage-path` attribute instead of `ssh-privateKey-storage-path` in your node definition, you can see the valid attributes [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-private-key-storage).